# Wicket DisableComponentListener disable whole page

Tags: ajax, components, wicket, javascript

I am using an ajax button in my wicket application and this code is working fine:

```
@Override
protected void updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes) {
    super.updateAjaxAttributes(attributes);
    attributes.getAjaxCallListeners().add(new DisableComponentListener(form));
}
```

form is a component with markup:id="form".

But I want to disable the whole WebPage object that is rendered,  and render the indicator as described [here](http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/ajax.html). Replacing form argument with getPage() inside DisableComponentListener does not seem to wok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've seen on the page you have linked to, the javascript code that "disables" the form uses the passed component's element id (= markup id) to disable it on client side.

The problem is the Page doesn't have a markup id. So you could either try edit your javascript code to use the body element or add a custom WebMarkupContainer higher up the hierarchy and pass this to your DisableComponentListener.

Comment: Thanks that works but how could I reach the WebMarkupContainer that belongs to a father page of my page?

Comment: you would need to provide a getter in your super class (after adding the WebMarkupContainer as field)